# What does classname.class return?

Tags: java, oop

Could anyone please explain what does `SomeClassname.class` return in JAVA ?? I cant understand what it does ..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It returns the same what [Object.getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) does for a given instance, but you can use it when you know statically what class you want (i.e. at compile time).

From the Javadoc:

> Returns the runtime class of this Object.

In short, it gives you an object that represents the *class* of the (original) object.  It's used, amongst other things, by [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) when you want to programatically discover methods and fields in order to invoke/access them.

For example:

```
        Method m[] = String.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        {
          System.out.println(m[i].toString());
        }
```

The Javadoc also refers you to the [Java Language Specification - Class Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) (which might be a little heavy reading).

Comment: What does SomeClass::class returns and it is different than that o SomeClass.class?

Answer (score 15):

It returns the Class object that represents the specified class name. This is used if you need to get the Class object.

This roughly corresponds to .getClass() which returns the Class object that corresponds to the object instance. You use someclassname.class when you want to work with the Class object and don't have an object instance.

Comment: Does this mean it returns the class instance?

Comment: @Rajeshwar no: e.g. `new Object()` returns a new instance of `Object`, but `Object.class` is and instance of the `Class<Object>` class. They are different things.

Comment: @Rajeshwar Did you take a look at what [the `Class` class is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)?

Comment: I'm quite confused. Why should SomeClassName.class be used to get a java.lang.Class object? Isn't SomeClassName already a java.lang.Class object? If not, what kind of object is SomeClassName?

Comment: SomeClassName on its own in the file is not a valid expression, so it doesn't represent any object. It's just the name of the class. It's a little like asking, "why should someMethod() be used to call the method? Isn't someMethod already the method?" Well, yes, but () is how you tell Java you want to call the method; and ".class" is how you tell java you want the object representing a class.

Answer (score 5):

.class is a class literal... Just like 5 is an int literal, like 5.0 is a double literal (surprisingly, there is a class named 'Class' in java.lang package).

Therefore you can print the class literal (just like you can print any object... you get what the toString() method returns in the Class class). You can have a Class variable.

PS: there are many functions that you can use

Answer (score 5):

Object.getclass = className.class

They both return the runtime class of the object

eg

```
Class lii = SomeClass.class;
Class leo = new SomeClass().getClass();
//lii==leo
```

Just like

```
String var1 = "heloo";
int var2 = 9;
float var3 = 8.0;
```

var1 stores "heloo" which is a String literal,
var2 stores 9 which is an integer literal,
var3 stores 8.0 which is a float literal,
so also lii and leo stores class literal generated from SomeClass.java file at runtime

Comment: What does SomeClass::class returns and it is different than that o SomeClass.class?

Answer (score 1):

Same as .getClass() method, but can be used only for named and void classes.
The .class syntax allows to obtain a Class if the type of object is available, but there is no instance.
Also, the easiest way to get a class for a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

It just like Class object = SomeClass.class;
The above statement will return the object of that particular class and will put it in Class Variable.
Hens it it wi return Class object.